# Beta testers are unable to trigger application through Google Assistant Voice Commands

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions

I have designed a custom intent to open my application and do a functionality using Google Assistant queries. I have tested the application by creating a preview using the app actions test tool, as well as by interacting with Google Assistant. In both cases, the application opens and does the intended functionality. Then I uploaded the application for Beta test release and my app actions were approved. But when the testers in the Beta tester list tried to open the application through voice commands it opens the web results, instead of opening my application. Do the testers need to do anything in particular to make this work or do I have to do anything particular after publishing the application in the google play console?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.